# How to remove HTML tags from the scraped data using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape news data where I want all the paragraphs of the news article. So I used `Soup.find_all('p')` to scrape all the paragraphs but it contains HTML tags and since `Soup.find_all('p')` will return `bs4.element.ResultSet` datatype I can't use other methods like `.get_text()` or `.decompose()` or `.stripe()`

And I can't use `Soup.find('p')` as it will give the first paragraph only and I need all the paragraphs.

Here is my code:

```
for story in J:
    page3 = requests.get(story)
    SOUP = BeautifulSoup(page3.content, 'html.parser')
    q = SOUP.find_all('p')
    print(q[0])
```

Output:[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQUw7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Simply iterate over your `ResultSet` to get the stripped text and `join()` the single texts by whitespace:

```
' '.join([p.get_text(strip=True) for p in SOUP.find_all('p')])
```

###### Example

```
for story in J:
    page3 = requests.get(story)
    SOUP = BeautifulSoup(page3.content, 'html.parser')
    t = ' '.join([p.get_text(strip=True) for p in SOUP.find_all('p')])
    print(t)
```